# JavaScript not working from time to time - SE wide

Tags: support, javascript

From time to time none of the JS-codes is working, and all sites (SE, AU, UL, GL&U, ...) are infected meanwhile, but with random exceptions.

I can't vote up, down, add a comment, don't get the toolbar for the edit box and so on.

I don't switch some settings in the browser, so JS isn't blocked, nothing. All that worked before and works normally.

I tried without success:

- reload the page
- Ctrl + reload the page
- disconnect and reconnect from the internet
- control JS-Settings
- check other settings
- disabled every greasemonkey - stuff (there isn't much)
- disabled ad block
- disabled popup blocker
- disabled referrer
- disabled proxy
- restarted Firefox (12.0 btw, but have experienced this before with former versions)
- deleted cache of today

I wanted to logout, but didn't find a logout option without js.
I don't get a "you should enable JS" warning.

If I make a "View source code" I see all the JS.

I have experienced this before and get crazy on it! It happens too rarely to give a good estimation: I'm a heavy user on more than one site here with several visits per day and site. It's about since 3 months since it happened the last time. The problem stays for hours. This time it started in the night, and might be clock-related, since it happened around midnight UTC. Next time I will try to look for that earlier.

The last settings I changed, related to Firefox where not for Firefox itself, but language-settings for Thunderbird, which didn't update as expected some hours earlier.

I don't think it's related, because in the beginning after that, SE worked well.

Comment: Do you use a virus scanner or ad blocker?  Does it help if you disable them?

Comment: see bullet 7: disabled ad-blocker (and normally it isn't disabled, and the pages work though). Virus scanner? Well, I'm using linux, if that answers your question. Alias: Of course not.

Comment: Some ad blockers hook traffic even when disabled, it might help to uninstall the ad blocker.  (Worked for me.)

Comment: @Andomar: Well - I disabled it, and can meanwhile access the meta site normally with the same settings. Are you sure the ad blocker is your problem? Does the problem reappear if you install it again? Maybe a coincidence?

Comment: For me it was the ad-blocker, the author of the blocker fixed it after :)  Your case is probably different, if I had to guess, I'd point at your browser.

Comment: How did you verify it was the Adblocker? My Adblocker is AdBlock Plus 2.0.3.

Comment: I was using Ad-Muncher.  If I closed it (not merely disable) the JS problem went away.